# Spark Data writing in Delta format

Tags: pyspark, delta-lake

Spark Version: 3.2.1
Delta version: 1.2.1 (tried 2.0 version as well)

While I am trying to run the getting started code to try out "delta".

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from delta import *
builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
data = spark.range(0, 5)
data.write.format("delta").save("/tmp/delta-table")
```

I am getting below error:
"name": "Py4JJavaError",
"message": "An error occurred while calling o201.showString.\n: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot find catalog plugin class for catalog 'spark_catalog'

Can anyone please help me understand the issue to resolve it?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which environment and mode are you using, but in general you need to add your jar by using the config `spark.jars.packages` because delta lake jar is not in Spark default jar. For example `.config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.2.0")`

Comment: any clue on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74035832/exception-occured-while-writing-delta-format-in-aws-s3 ?

Comment: The line `spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()` takes care of adding that particular config with (presumably) the correct maven coordinates before creating the Spark session. It it standard according to https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#python